# Get ESRI maps in Microstrategy Desktop behind a proxy

Tags: proxy, microstrategy

I´m running Microstrategy Desktop v. 10.5.0 on Windows 10 and I´m trying to build a few maps. I´m behind a HTTP proxy in the format

```
http_proxy=http://<user>:<password>@proxy.mycorp.com:8080
https_proxy=http://<user>:<password>@proxy.mycorp.com:8080
```

and every time I try to start a map I get the message

```
Unable to download the ESRI map. No Internet connection. You can configure an Internet proxy through you computer´s Settings.
```

The internet works for all other programs with the same proxy and the ESRI CDN links also work directly on the browser behind the proxy. If I connect to a network outside my work connection and disable the proxy the maps work. Is there a way to make Microstrategy Desktop work behind a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please look into the following link, You have to check with your network admins and request them to unblock some websites and ports.

https://community.microstrategy.com/t5/Clients-Interfaces/Sporadic-issues-with-ESRI-maps-in-Desktop-10-with-proxy-setting/td-p/248444

We faced the same issue, and we requested our network admin team to do the following :

For simpicity, you could open below configuration in the firewall:

1. Ports 443 , 80 and 6080
2. *.arcgis.com, *.esri.com and *.arcgisonline.com

Answer (score 0):

Starting with MicroStrategy Analytics Enterprise 9.4.1 Hotfix 6 and in MicroStrategy 10.X, users are able to configure MicroStrategy Web to send HTTP request to ESRI via internal proxy servers. The following provides the details
**Un-authenticated proxy** :
If the proxy server does not require authentication, user can go to Web Administration security page and configure the following settigs

1. Go to Web Administration --> Security Page.
2. Check "Enable HTTP proxy server"
3. Fill out the Server address and Server port
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI1uB.png)

**Authenticated proxy server**
It the proxy server requires authentication , User will need to add  in the esriconfig.xml file located under plugins\ConnectorForESRIMap\WEB-INF\xml\config (see sample below).
Note: Restart the web server after this change

```
<ec> <apps clientToken="true"> <key><![CDATA[------]]></key></apps></ec>
```